# Find exact value of $\tan(\frac{17\pi}{12})$ using 2 methods, one of which fails.

Tags: trigonometry

When I try to use an identity to break this apart and get an exact value for it, I stumbled on an interesting snag which I would like to get an explanation for.

$\tan(\frac{17\pi}{12})$

So one way to break this apart is to break off the $\frac{17\pi}{12}$ into $\frac{8\pi}{12}$ (=$\frac{2\pi}{3}$)and $\frac{9\pi}{12}$ (=$\frac{3\pi}{4}$) then use the identity $$\tan(A+B)=\frac{\tan(A)+\tan(B)}{1-\tan(A)\tan(B)}$$

Which works just fine and evaluates to $2+\sqrt3$

Now:

My understanding is that we should be able to break that original fraction off in any way we please and arrive at the answer. So let's do so in this way:

Break off the $\frac{17\pi}{12}$ into $\frac{18\pi}{12}$ (=$\frac{3\pi}{2}$) and $\frac{-\pi}{12}$

Now Notice that $\tan(\frac{3\pi}{2})$ is undefined due to the asymptote there [same as $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2})$].

So why is it that when we break it that way it gets to an undefined state?  Are there any general rules I need to follow in breaking angles down? How come the above won't work that way?

-Thanks

Comment: you can't "break off"  using $3\pi/2$  an use the tan formula. However, you may write it as $\pi  + \frac{5}{12}$  and find joy

Comment: Well we technically can break it off in any which way we please - hence the question

Comment: What happens if you use your formula to find $ \tan \left( \pi + \frac{5 \pi}{12}  \right)  \; \; ?  \; \; \; $

Comment: Yeah works just fine also: 0+(2+sqrt(3)) - what's the point being made here? There are obviously any number of ways to do this

Comment: You can avoid the problems at angles where tangent is undefined by using the fact that $$\tan(\alpha + \beta) = \frac{\sin(\alpha + \beta)}{\cos(\alpha + \beta)}$$ unless $\cos(\alpha + \beta)  = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly substitute the $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ directly as the reasons you noted. However, we can take a limit. We know that
$$\tan \left(\frac{17\pi}{12}\right)=\lim_{x\to \frac{18\pi}{12}} \frac{\tan x+\tan \left(-\frac{\pi}{12}\right)}{1-\tan x\tan\left(-\frac{\pi}{12}\right)}$$
Note that as $x\to \frac{18\pi}{12}$, we have $\tan x\to \infty$, so this is equivalent to
$$\tan \left(\frac{17\pi}{12}\right)=\lim_{u\to \infty} \frac{u+\tan \left(-\frac{\pi}{12}\right)}{1-u\tan\left(-\frac{\pi}{12}\right)}$$
Using horizontal asymptote theorem (or you can conclude this with algebraic or other methods), we know that this is equivalent to
$$\tan \left(\frac{17\pi}{12}\right)=\frac{1}{-\tan\left(-\frac{\pi}{12}\right)}$$
$$\tan \left(\frac{17\pi}{12}\right)=\frac{1}{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{12}\right)}$$
However, this is also not too hard to prove geometrically (draw a unit circle), and is not much useful for calculating the value of $\tan\left(\frac{17\pi}{12}\right)$. The reason why we split $\frac{17\pi}{12}$ into $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ is because we already know the values of $\tan\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)$ and $\tan\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)$. On the other hand, using your method I'm assuming you don't already know the value of $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{12}\right)$, so it's not as useful.

Comment: Thanks @Alan Abraham! So we have no choice but to take the Limit there? isn't it odd that we must?  Also your last 2 lines are identical there, did you mean that?

Comment: Oh, that second line wasn't supposed to be there, but I guess I can repurpose it. The reason we have to take the limit is because we are dealing with indeterminate behavior. I do get what you mean by it seeming inconsistent, but it's just another way of evaluating that expression when we are dealing with infinities and other indeterminate forms.

Comment: Ok gocha - I assume it's just that 1 way is easier than another. That's all. also: in general is there a systematic way of breaking these angles down? I broke the numerator to 9 and 8 since that was closest to a half, which worked out well. Can I always use that technique?...then keep dividing further into halves where needed?

Comment: @Steve237 You want to break down $\frac{17\pi}{12}$ into fractions that you know the tangent of. You should be able to easily determine the tangent of every multiple of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{\pi}{6}$ (you can find even more with some nontrivial trig identities). You know that $\frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{2\pi}{12}$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{3\pi}{12}$. So you want to split $17$ into some integer combination of $2$ and $3$. For example, you could do $17=2\cdot 4+3\cdot 3$, which means you would split $\frac{17\pi}{12}$ into $\frac{4\pi}{6}$ and $\frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Comment: @Steve237 (continued from the previous comment) this is the break down you showed in your question. You can also break down $17$ into $2\cdot 1+3\cdot 5$. This would mean you split $\frac{17\pi}{12}$ into $\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $\frac{5\pi}{4}$. You can also split $17$ into $2\cdot 7+3\cdot 1$. This would mean you split $\frac{17\pi}{12}$ into $\frac{7 \pi}{6}$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}$. These are the only positive integer combinations, but you can also use negative integer combinations. All of these will yield the same answer, so you might be better off using positive integers, but you just need one.

Comment: Right, good point, so our starting point would be the observation of Pi/4 and Pi/6 multiples, then we can see that the solution would be a multiple of 2 and 3 only to make up 17, hence 3m+2n=17, which there are only 3 positive solutions of: {{n -> 1, m -> 5}, {n -> 4, m -> 3}, {n -> 7, m -> 1}} , BUT note you could have used Pi/3 as well! In fact I just generalized something...

Comment: @Steve237 That sounds about right. However, I do not think you can use $\frac{\pi}{3}$. as $\frac{17\pi}{12}-\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{13\pi}{12}$, which does not have an easily determined tangent.